# How to write a query in spring for inserting records into 2 tables in Mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I want to write a query to insert data into two tables.

I am inserting data into two tables know as `User` and `company`.
`User` has foreign key `company _id`. Table structure is given blow

**User table**

- int user_id;(AI)
- int company_id; (foreign key)
- String user_name;
- String user_email;

**Company table**

- int company_id;(AI)
- String company_name;

-

```
void insert(String user){
    String query="insert into user(user_name,user_email,company_id,company_name) values
    (variable,variable, variable, variable)";
    //code to map using put method
}
```

I am getting an error

```
company_id cannot be null.
```

Comment: Please edit your question, so it'll be clear. It's not readable now.

Comment: thank you @Anna for editing question.Company_id is fk so its not null.so please let me know query changes

Answer (score 0):

This probably because your `company_id` is set to `not null` in the `user` table. You have to remove `not null` from the `company_id` column in your table creation statement of the `user` table, if you want foreign key to be nullable. Otherwise you have to provide a value for the foreign key.

Comment: Company_id is fk so its not null.so please let me know query changes

Answer (score 0):

As the foreign key `company_id` cannot be `null`, the company must exist in the DB and it's id must be known before you can insert the user.

UPDATE

To insert a new user you need:

- a user name
- an e-mail address
- a company name

We first need to search the `company_id` for the given company name. If it is not found in the database, a new company is inserted.

```
public void insertUser(String userName, String userEmail, String companyName)
        throws SQLException {
    int companyId = getOrInsertCompany(companyName);
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = cnt.prepareStatement(
            "insert into User(company_id,user_name,user_email)"
            + " values(?,?,?)")) {
        stmt.setInt(1, companyId);
        stmt.setString(1, userName);
        stmt.setString(1, userEmail);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
}

private int getOrInsertCompany(String companyName) throws SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = cnt.prepareStatement(
            "select company_id from Company where company_name=?")) {
        stmt.setString(1, companyName);
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getInt(1);
            }
        }
    }
    // the company was not found; insert it
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = cnt.prepareStatement(
            "insert into Company(company_name) values(?)")) {
        stmt.setString(1, companyName);
        stmt.execute();
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            if (!rs.next()) {
                throw new SQLException(
                        "Could not get generated keys");
            }
            return rs.getInt(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Company_id is fk so its not null.so please let me know query changes

Comment: @Minakshi you need three actually

Comment: pls do let me know how to write query then

Comment: We don't have enough information to completely answer the question: what's the schema, how are IDs allocated? autoincrement? sequences?

Comment: Its simple database i have updated info (AI).. no sequences...

Comment: @Minakshi see my UPDATE

Comment: You may need to do a commit the insert

Answer (score 0):

Check for the NOT NULL constraint

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'user' and column_name = 'company_id';
```

If the value of is_nullable is `NO`, then you cannot insert null value.

Either, change the constraint to `NULL`, or validate (not null value) your value for company_id.

Syntax to change constraint from NOT NULL to NULL

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn columnType NULL
```